# Let X be a compact metric space. Show there is a Borel measure $\mu$.

Tags: measure-theory

Body:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Then there is a regular Borel measure $\mu$, such that if $f$ is any nonnegative continuous function on $X$ with $f\neq 0$, then $\int f\,{\rm d}\mu > 0$.

My answer:

As $X = \bigcup_{x\in X}B(x,1)$ and as $X$ is compact, there are a finite number of $x_{i}$ terms such that their balls of radius $1$ covers $X$. Then by looking at balls of radius $1/2$, $1/n$, ..., there are a finite number of terms such that the balls of radius $1/n$ for those terms covers $X$.
Because a countable union of finite sets is countable, we get a dense subset of $X$.
Define $\mu$ as a measure of Borel set by counting how many of the $x_{i}$ terms are in the certain Borel set.
It can be easy to see that any integral by this measure is strictly greater than $0$.
$\mu$ should be countably additive, so that it would be a Borel measure. But I don’t know how to prove it is regular.
Does anyone have any other solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(x_n)$ be a countable dense set and $\mu =\sum_n 2^{-n}\delta_{x_n}$. Then $\mu$ has the desired properties. [Every non-empty open set has positive measure. Every finite Borel measure on a  compact metric space is regular Ref: Billingsley, Convergence of Probability Measures].